# Implement a lambda function to get a range of year referencing the current year as list with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does anyone know of a lambda function that can be implemented to get a range of year roughly +/- 3 years from the current year as a list?

Currently, what I'm doing is:

```
oneYear = datetime.datetime.now().year - 1
twoYear= datetime.datetime.now().year - 2
threeYear= datetime.datetime.now().year - 3

oneYearFuture = datetime.datetime.now().year + 1
twoYearFuture = datetime.datetime.now().year + 1
threeYearFuture = datetime.datetime.now().year + 1

years = [oneYear, twoYear, threeYear, datetime.datetime.now().year, oneYearFuture, twoYearFuture, threeYearFuture ]
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you need a lambda function? A list comprehension over `range(-3, 4)` would get this done.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my purpose is just to be able to get a range of year +/- 3 years as array instead of manually hardcoding it

Comment: Yes, I understand that, my question is: why do you think a lambda function helps you do that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because from what I read about lamda function, they are an iife and pretty much a one liner function. I'm still pretty shallow regarding python knowledge.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"EFI"* but yes, they're a one liner (strictly: single expression) function. That does't answer my question, though - how are you planning to use such a function? Did you try writing one? What happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I shall look up this list comprehension you mentioned thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
current_year = datetime.now().year
delta_years = 3
years = [current_year+x for x in range(-delta_years, delta_years+1)]
print(years)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> list(map(lambda x: datetime.now().year +x,[num_years for num_years in range(-3,4)]))
[2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
```

Comment: `list(map(...))` is an anti-pattern (see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), and makes no sense at all when you do it over *what's already a list comprehension*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know that list comprehension is the way to get the result, but I just mentioned it with lambda as asked in question. You are correct, I should have posted the right way to do.

Answer (score -1):

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> year_range = lambda x: range(x -3, x + 4)
>>> year_range(datetime.date.today().year)
[2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]
```

Comment: `lambda`s are useful for *anonymous* functions, if you're assigning it to a name just write a regular `def` function.